# Setting state setState() inside ComponentDidUpdate() going to infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If someone can help me with this ? 
I need this function to store the `filteredObject` key in the state. but when I call this function in `componentDidMount()`,  it didn't work and when I called it in `ComponentDidUpdate()` it works but going on a infinite loop?

```
userData = () => {
    const returnedEmail = storageManger.getEmailFromStore();
    const { agents } = this.state;
    if (returnedEmail) {
        const filteredEmail = agents.find(agent => { return agent.email === returnedEmail })        
        if (filteredEmail) {
            this.setState({
                agentApplicationId: filteredEmail.properties
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure of this use? :  "const { agents } = this.state;"

Comment: When do you need to run this `userData` function? Meaning depending on changes to which specific values? Looks like `agents` is relevant here, but how do you manage changes to `returnedEmail`?

Comment: For all the life cycle which gets triggered after change in props and state will definitely run into same situation. It will go to infinite loop and max call stack if you try setting state. Can you try doing this when you get the returnedEmail from storage. Then you try executing in mounting life cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful when setting state in `componentDidUpdate`. Calling `setState` updates the component, which triggers `componentDidUpdate`, which calls `setState`, and so on, causing the infinite loop. From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

> You may call `setState()` immediately in `componentDidUpdate()` but note that it must be wrapped in a condition...or you’ll cause an infinite loop.

The solution is to add some kind of condition so you're not updating state unnecessarily. For example:

```
userData = () => {
  const returnedEmail = storageManger.getEmailFromStore();
  const { agents, agentApplicationId } = this.state;

  if (returnedEmail) {
    const filteredEmail = agents.find(agent => agent.email === returnedEmail);

    // Add an extra condition here to prevent state from updating if the values are already equal.
    if (filteredEmail && filteredEmail.properties !== agentApplicationId) {
      this.setState({
        agentApplicationId: filteredEmail.properties
      });
    }
  }
}
```